# Sql query put to php function

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a `if/else` condition in `Yii Framework`. When the user is admin the database query should not have a filter and if the user is not admin the database query should have a filter.

```html
 if($ut=='Admin'){ // if the user is Admin the query should not have a filter
    $queryCustomer = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->select('cust.mobile_number as customer,sum(trans.price) as sales,trans.datetime')
    ->from('customers cust')
       ->join('transactions trans', 'cust.id=trans.customer_id')
       ->where('transaction_type_id=:id', array(':id'=>1)) 
       ->group('customer_id')
       ->order('trans.datetime DESC')
       ->queryAll();
        $per_customer=$this->renderTableCustomer($queryCustomer);
        } else { // if the user is not Admin the query should have a filter
         $queryCustomer = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->select('cust.mobile_number as customer,sum(trans.price) as sales,trans.datetime')
    ->from('customers cust')
       ->join('transactions trans', 'cust.id=trans.customer_id')
       ->where('transaction_type_id=:id', array(':id'=>1))
       ->andWhere('user_id=:userID',array(':userID'=>$filter))  
       ->group('customer_id')
       ->order('trans.datetime DESC')
       ->queryAll();
    $per_customer=$this->renderTableCustomer($queryCustomer);
```

The queries is the same except I added a where statement in else query. Since the query is same, is there a possibility to put it on a function and when I call it I will add the where statement as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a function. You can do it like this:

```html
$queryCustomer = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->select('cust.mobile_number as customer,sum(trans.price) as sales,trans.datetime')
    ->from('customers cust')
      ->join('transactions trans', 'cust.id=trans.customer_id')
      ->where('transaction_type_id=:id', array(':id'=>1)) 

if($ut !== 'Admin') // if the user is Admin the query should not have a filter
            ->andWhere('user_id=:userID',array(':userID'=>$filter)) 

            ->group('customer_id')
            ->order('trans.datetime DESC')
            ->queryAll();

$per_customer=$this->renderTableCustomer($queryCustomer);
```

in this way, if the user is not an Admin, that `->addWhere()` method will not execute. So the function is needles, so as the double query for a single method call...

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Hi thanks for the revision of my codes. :-) I tried it, but nothing is displayed. No data and totally blank. I check the error log and the error says is "[Mon Nov 03 09:05:33.003173 2014] [:error] [pid 2956] [client 127.0.0.1:36533] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /var/www/html/savenearn22_2014/protected/controllers/TransactionsController.php on line 220, referer: http://localhost/savenearn22_2014/index.php?r=transactions/reportsperproduct
". I think it is because the if statement. Why I am getting this error? help, thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to change the code to this inside the `IF` block `$queryCustomer->andWhere('user_id=:userID',array(':userID'=>$filter));`